# Query returns null when attributes of nodes of an XML are queried in oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

I have a huge XML file and I have uploaded it in an oracle table. I want to show attributes of the nodes defined in XML as attributes of a table. Below is the DDL of the table where XML is stored.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_USER.XML_TAB
(
  ID        NUMBER,
  XML_DATA  SYS.XMLTYPE
);
```

So far I have managed to built the following query, but the problem with this query is that it returns no data which is against attributes of the node selected.

```
   SELECT  x.*
     FROM XML_TAB t,
          XMLTABLE ('/ProductDataeXchangePackage/Items/Item'
                    PASSING t.XML_DATA
                    COLUMNS 
  CATEGORY                        VARCHAR2(19 BYTE) PATH '/ProductDataeXchangePackage/Items/Item/@CATEGORY', 
  DESCRIPTION                     VARCHAR2(91 BYTE) PATH '/ProductDataeXchangePackage/Items/Item/@DESCRIPTION', 
  GLOBALLIFECYCLEPHASECODE        VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) PATH '/ProductDataeXchangePackage/Items/Item/@GLOBALLIFECYCLEPHASECODE', 
  GLOBALPRODUCTTYPECODE           VARCHAR2(19 BYTE) PATH '/ProductDataeXchangePackage/Items/Item/@GLOBALPRODUCTTYPECODE', 
  GLOBALPRODUCTUNITOFMEASURECODE  VARCHAR2(2 BYTE) PATH '/ProductDataeXchangePackage/Items/Item/@GLOBALPRODUCTUNITOFMEASURECODE', 
  ISTOPLEVEL                      VARCHAR2(3 BYTE) PATH '/ProductDataeXchangePackage/Items/Item/@ISTOPLEVEL', 
  ITEMIDENTIFIER                  VARCHAR2(7 BYTE) PATH '/ProductDataeXchangePackage/Items/Item/@ITEMIDENTIFIER', 
  ITEMUNIQUEIDENTIFIER            VARCHAR2(14 BYTE) PATH '/ProductDataeXchangePackage/Items/Item/@ITEMUNIQUEIDENTIFIER', 
  OWNERNAME                       VARCHAR2(17 BYTE) PATH '/ProductDataeXchangePackage/Items/Item/@OWNERNAME', 
  PROPRIETARYPRODUCTFAMILY        VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) PATH '/ProductDataeXchangePackage/Items/Item/@PROPRIETARYPRODUCTFAMILY', 
  REVISIONIDENTIFIER              VARCHAR2(11 BYTE) PATH '/ProductDataeXchangePackage/Items/Item/@REVISIONIDENTIFIER', 
  REVISIONRELEASEDDATE            VARCHAR2(25 BYTE) PATH '/ProductDataeXchangePackage/Items/Item/@REVISIONRELEASEDDATE') x;
```

Following XML is not the original XML with which I am working on. But it shows that node on which I am trying to fetch data from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

                        <ProductDataeXchangePackage 
                            thisDocumentIdentifier="_33998998" 
                            thisDocumentGenerationDateTime="2016-01-31T23:36:48-08:00" 
                            thisDocumentModificationDateTime="2016-01-31T23:36:48-08:00" 
                            originatedByContactName="Affan Ahmed"
                            packageType="Arena Solutions ProductDataeXchangePackage"
                            dataSource="Arena Solutions"
                            thisDocumentCopyright="Arena Solutions">

            <Items>

                                    <Item
                                        itemIdentifier="1102607" 
                                        itemUniqueIdentifier="IVI10439707838"
                                        globalLifeCyclePhaseCode="Production"
                                        globalProductTypeCode="Finished Goods SWI"
                                        revisionIdentifier="4"
                                        proprietaryProductFamily=""
                                        category="Finished Goods SWI"
                                        globalProductUnitOfMeasureCode="EA"
                                        revisionReleasedDate="2015-12-04T21:33:02-08:00"
                                        ownerName="Rajesh Prashar"
                                        isTopLevel="Yes"
                                        description="EM7455,DELL,GENERIC,02.04.07.00,,AVMS,GNSS=ABC,CUSTMR IMEI,USB,E7 TABLET (JAYTON)">
                                        <AdditionalAttributes groupLabel="Version Information">
                                            <AdditionalAttribute name="Version Notes" value="ECO for updating SKU to R10 FW1) 1102607   EM7455,DELL,GENERIC,02.04.07.00,,AVMS,GNSS=ABC,CUSTMR IMEI,USB,E7 TABLET (JAYTON)Updating FW/PRI/FACT2) 9904717   SETTINGS FILE (NVUP + CFG), 1102607New file attached to the new revisionSBM 19926 - Update Template, ParserTool, BuildScript. Update FW and Carrier to 02.04.07.00.  Add persistence to factory values. Clear AutoStart SettingsFactory Implementation Instruction:======================Update production system. Validation:a) Configure 2 modems under shop floor system.b) Perform verification on these two modems. Name the two config tool output folders as “1” and “2”c) In the “1” and “2” folders, take two screen captures:i. one of factory running the configuration program, showing all parameters and system status. Name this test.jpgii. one of factory having completed configuration program, showing all parameters and system status. Name this pass.jpgd) Add configuration log files and .out files to the folders &quot;1&quot; and &quot;2&quot;e) Take a screen capture of shop floor system screen captures on the SKU setup. Name each file as shopfloor1.jpg, shopfloor2.jpg, and shopfloor3.jpgf) Put all files and folders from (i) and (ii) above into a zip file entitled 11xxxxx-revz_ECOyyyy (where z is the revision of the SKU). Example: 1101001-2_ECO1234.zip2) Upload all SKU validation files to &quot;Implementation&quot; tab of the ECO and set implementation status to &quot;Needs Attention&quot;3) Upon Sierra&apos;s review/confirmation and Implementation Status set to &quot;Done&quot;; the SKU will be shippable.Disposition:Effectivity of Instructions: Immediate upon ECO being approvedRework inventory:   YESMixed shipment permitted:  NOFactory NOT authorized to build and ship during interval between ECO effective and implementation datePassed module during this ECO validation: Release for normal shipment/Re-SKU based on backlogFailed module during this ECO validation: Hold modules and wait for SWIR further instructionsFactory authorized to rework SKUs older than 30 days back to the buffer level" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
                                            <AdditionalAttribute name="Change Number" value="ECO-017282" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
                                            <AdditionalAttribute name="Version Shared" value="Yes" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
                                            <AdditionalAttribute name="Effective Version Shared" value="Yes" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
                                            <AdditionalAttribute name="Material Effectivity Date" value="2015-12-04T21:33:02-08:00" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>

                                    <AdditionalAttribute name="Internal Item Identifier" value="GYHZI2L2L43L6JWQ" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>                    
                                    <AdditionalAttribute name="Internal Version Identifier" value="5N6O7RAI1G733GVK" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>                    
                                    <AdditionalAttribute name="Item Creation Date" value="2015-06-23T17:25:32-08:00" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>                    

                                        </AdditionalAttributes>
               <AdditionalAttributes groupLabel="Permanent Link Information">
                <AdditionalAttribute name="Item Specification Summary" value="https://app.bom.com/a/GYHZI2L2L43L6JWQ?v=spec.summary"  dataType="UriReference" ></AdditionalAttribute>
                             </AdditionalAttributes>

                                        <AdditionalAttributes groupLabel="Category Information">
                        <AdditionalAttribute name="Category Name" value="Finished Goods SWI" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
                        <AdditionalAttribute name="Category Path" value="Finished Goods SWI" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
                    </AdditionalAttributes>
                    <AdditionalAttributes groupLabel="Arena Solutions Custom Attributes">
                <AdditionalAttribute name="Arena Solutions Description" value=""  dataType="String" ></AdditionalAttribute>
                             <AdditionalAttribute name="Procurement Type" value="Off-the-Shelf (OTS)"  dataType="String" ></AdditionalAttribute>
                             <AdditionalAttribute name="Commodity Class" value="FG - Finished Goods"  dataType="String" ></AdditionalAttribute>
                             <AdditionalAttribute name="Requestor" value=""  dataType="String" ></AdditionalAttribute>
                             <AdditionalAttribute name="Stocking Type" value="P - Purchased"  dataType="String" ></AdditionalAttribute>
                             <AdditionalAttribute name="Product Family" value="E7455 - EM7455"  dataType="String" ></AdditionalAttribute>
                             <AdditionalAttribute name="EDI Product Code" value=""  dataType="String" ></AdditionalAttribute>
                             <AdditionalAttribute name="EDI Partner" value=""  dataType="String" ></AdditionalAttribute>
                             <AdditionalAttribute name="MFG Branch - Intellectual Property" value="295 - SWI - Vietnam"  dataType="String" ></AdditionalAttribute>
                             <AdditionalAttribute name="UPC/EAN" value=""  dataType="String" ></AdditionalAttribute>
                             <AdditionalAttribute name="SKU Parameters" value="DellREV = A00CustomerPN = 3MDGKDellSKU = DW5811e MFGID = 77892FCC = N7NEM7455-D2IC = 2417C-EM7455Customer Serial Number (Field 37) = YESVendorID = 77892LocID = 77892"  dataType="String" ></AdditionalAttribute>
                             </AdditionalAttributes>

<Other child nodes of node Item>
.
.
.
.
</Other child nodes of node Item>
</Item>

<Other child nodes of node Items>
.
.
.
.
</Other child nodes of node Items>
</Items>

<Other child nodes of root node ProductDataeXchangePackage>
.
.
.
.
</Other child nodes of node ProductDataeXchangePackage>

</ProductDataeXchangePackage>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I suppose nobody wanted to help or was quite busy. I have found a solution and I am posting it so that anybody out there who was stuck like me could find a solution. Here is the answer to the problem.

Using xmlsequence function did the trick.

```
SELECT extractvalue(column_value, 'Item/@itemIdentifier') itemIdentifier,
         extractvalue(column_value, 'Item/@itemUniqueIdentifier') itemUniqueIdentifier,
         extractvalue(column_value, 'Item/@globalLifeCyclePhaseCode') globalLifeCyclePhaseCode,
         extractvalue(column_value, 'Item/@globalProductTypeCode') globalProductTypeCode,
         extractvalue(column_value, 'Item/@revisionIdentifier') revisionIdentifier,
         extractvalue(column_value, 'Item/@proprietaryProductFamily') proprietaryProductFamily,
         extractvalue(column_value, 'Item/@category') category,
         extractvalue(column_value, 'Item/@globalProductUnitOfMeasureCode') globalProductUnitOfMeasureCode,
         extractvalue(column_value, 'Item/@revisionReleasedDate') revisionReleasedDate,
         extractvalue(column_value, 'Item/@ownerName') ownerName,
         extractvalue(column_value, 'Item/@isTopLevel') isTopLevel,
         extractvalue(column_value, 'Item/@description') description

    FROM TABLE (SELECT xmlsequence(x.XML_DATA.extract('ProductDataeXchangePackage/' ||
                                             'Items/' ||
                                             'Item'))
                   FROM XML_TAB x);
```